# Creating SIMPLIS model from IC Internal Architecture Datasheet (SMPS PWM IC)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, datasheet

I intended to design offline SMPS using Two Switch Forward Topology with NCP1252 IC from onsemi.

But before jump directly into hardware prototyping, I intended to design it first on SIMPLIS (as it is PWL and fast enough to do the simulation). I need to simulate it to get a grasp on the feedback loop and compensation circuit design. But, onsemi doesn't have premade SIMPLIS model for NCP1252E. I looked into the datasheet and found their internal circuit architecture shown as below:

[image: Internal Architecture of NCP1252]

My question is, does anyone has a step by step guide on creating the model from the IC internal architecture? its okay if it was from another IC, at least I hope it could guide me on step by step IC design, so that I can be ready to copy the above IC to SIMPLIS.

Comment: I doubt there's any guide, but it all starts by looking at the schematic and trying to determine what each building block does and how it can be best approximated. You have there logic gates, latches, opamps, comparators, various primitives, and some complex ones. Some elements can be simplified (e.g. the output MOSFETs, use VCSW), others (the oscillator) will require building it out of several elements. You're in for quite a task ahead of you (if it was easy then everybody would do it) so expect to waste some time on this, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the input @aconcernedcitizen , i agree with you that i need to know how each blocks works, for now i think i will use christophe basso SIMPLIS model on current mode two switch forward isolated, while learning basic current mode buck converter works, i think generally they work the same, and hopes that by learning them will makes me understand and play with the above IC. Thanks again.